# What is the term for an expression such as, "Now we're cooking with gas."

Tags: expressions, terminology

I have been looking for the term used for expressions such as "Now we're cooking with gas" for a while and even google couldn't answer it.

Comment: If you could add in a couple more examples, or explain which feature of this expression you would like to categorize, that would help. For example [Idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiom), [slogan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slogan), or [reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reference) could be used to describe this expression

Comment: Google: "Now you're cooking with gas" which refers to a 1930s commercial touting the benefits of gas stoves (vs wood stoves) - Source: https://www.waywordradio.org/cooking-with-gas-origin/

Comment: I Googled ["Now we're cooking with gas"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Now+we%27re+cooking+with+gas%22&oq=%22Now+we%27re+cooking+with+gas%22&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and found *…originated in the late 1930's or early 40s as a **slogan** thought up by the natural gas industry to convince people to ...* Call those types of expressions sprung/conceived by the world of  advertising: *Slogan*, *tagline*, *catchphrase* ; they're all related.

Comment: What do you mean by “expressions such as ‘Now we’re cooking with gas’”? Without knowing what aspect of that expression you’re looking for a name for, how can we know which expressions you’d consider similar?

Comment: @katatahito It could also be thought of as a metaphor like "we're steaming ahead" or "now we're flying" which are both used sometimes to comment on the way a task which has nothing to do with transport is being performed.

Comment: @BoldBen yep, my list was in no way exhaustive, mostly to illustrate that this question should be put on hold until it is edited to add more context and information

Comment: When a slogan or motto catches on in the world outside the context in which it was originally intended to apply, it is sometimes referred to as a **catchphrase**. [Merriam-Webster online defines _catchphrase_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catchphrase) as follows: "1 : a word or expression that is used repeatedly and conveniently to represent or characterize a person, group, idea, or point of view 2 : SLOGAN sense 2 ['a brief attention-getting phrase used in advertising or promotion']."
"

Comment: For me it was always "Now you're cooking with gas and electricity", since the guy I often heard it from worked for the Louisville Gas and Electric Company.

Answer (score 1):

Idioms or a colloquial phrase.  I think they are most commonly referred to as Idioms though.

Comment: Please could you take the time to explain how either of those word could be the answer

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "now you're cooking with gas" originates in Britain in the 1930s when gas companies paid popular radio shows to use the phrase with the meaning "you're on the right track."

https://www.waywordradio.org/cooking-with-gas-origin/

The phrase continued in to the television advertising era:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJRQo5aawho

And has become part of the popular British English lexicon.

It is an example of quiet marketing to sell gas stoves.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. It didn’t ask for the meaning or etymology of the example sentence. I’m flagging this as Not An Answer. You can edit your post to address the question, or delete your post to avoid further downvotes. See [answer] for further guidance. :-)

Comment: Why do you think this is of British origin? The linked webpage doesn't mention the UK but it does mention radio advertising and the natural gas industry. In the 1930s most British radio was supplied by the BBC which has never been commercial, there was no natural gas industry except the Calor bottled gas company (which was only started in 1935), mains gas was town gas made from coal and most of it was supplied by county-council-owned public utilities.